# ¿Cómo revisar que un texto se escriba de cierto formato?

Tags: javascript, regex, condiciones

Estoy haciendo una base de datos para piezas de un taller mecánico en Google Sheets con ayuda de Google Apps Script. En el formulario de entrada de datos, se puede ingresar el nombre de la pieza, pero parte del control de este sistema es el formato que tienen los nombres de las piezas, por ejemplo:

**240.250.D1.1** sería el nombre de una pieza, siendo los primeros 2 números las medidas, el tercero sería la posición y el último sería su identificación.

El problema que tengo es al momento de ingresar piezas nuevas, quiero que quien sea que esté aquí para operar la base de datos solo pueda ingesar nombres en ese formato, dicho formato vendría siendo:

*ValorAlfaNumérico.ValorAlfaNumérico.ValorAlfaNumérico.ValorAlfaNumérico*

No quisiera que por andar en prisa o por flojera, llenen en el nombre "La pieza roja".

El código que necesito sería de este estilo:

```
if (NombreDeLaPieza != "Aquí ingresaría la validación que necesito"){
  interface.alert("Nombre de la pieza mal escrita, recuerda usar el formato adecuado (Carrera.Base.Anaquel.Identificador)");
  return
}
```

Comment: Espero que tu objetivo no sea que te hagamos la tarea... Qué has intentado? Ya probaste una expresión regular? Creo que un poquito de investigación y/o prueba-error puede ayudarte bastante en tu carrera profesional

Comment: No, estoy en prácticas profesionales y tengo profesores asignados que me pueden ayudar, pero ninguno me contesta y ya investigué pero no encuentro lo que busco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé programar en ese lenguaje, pero a simple vista se me ocurre hacer un split, usando el . como caracter separador.

De esta forma, podrías crear un array y comprobar con RegEx cada una. Por ejemplo:

```
nombrePieza = "240.250.D1.1";
arrayPieza = nombrePieza.split(".");

//De esta forma tendrías
arrayPieza[0] = "240";
arrayPieza[1] = "250";
arrayPieza[2] = "D1";
arrayPieza[3] = "1";
```

Le pasas un RegEx alfanumérico a cada uno de los valores del array y si todos estan OK, devuelves un true.

No sé si te he podido enfocar un poco. Así lo haría yo.

Saludos

Comment: Por qué no un regex para todo el string?

Comment: Mis conocimientos en Regex no son tan extensos, si sabes cómo hacerlo, cuéntame!

Comment: Los míos tampoco, sin embargo, creo que buscar en google "regex alphanumeric" puede ayudar arrojar resultados interesantes, no? Además, creo que con un poco de investigación se puede aprender a hacerlo

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte

Comment: A la orden . Espero sea de utilidad para respuestas futuras.

Comment: La verdad es que no, has dicho lo que ya sabía (mi comentario era irónico)

Comment: @secu me parece buena idea la del split, ya que tampoco se manejar muy bien el regex para algo tan largo y no se mucho de JavaScript, pero si no ingresan el nombre de la p ieza como se debe, el split no funcionaría

Comment: @secu usando tu idea del array y el split pude resolver mi duda, no tuve que utilizar Regex. Lo que hice fue el split, y en el If le pregunté si el largo de mi array era menor a 4, que le dijera al usuario que el nombre está mal escrito, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera, que para eso es este foro! Un abrazo

Comment: Aunque usaría regex para revisar que no se metan caracteres como @ etc, https://regexland.com/regex-for-alphanumeric-strings/ @AndresLugo